# Pandas: Length of dataframe different than the sum of concatenated .dat files

Tags: pandas, concatenation

```
import pandas as pd
result=pd.concat([pd.read_table(f, sep="\s+") for f in filename], ignore_index=True)
```

**filename** is a list with the names of the .dat files I am using. Every file has 1440 rows and 4 columns. However the total length of the dataframe I am getting is not an integer multiple of 1440. Does anyone suspect what is wrong here?

Comment: What is the length of final dataframe? Can you reproduce this with two small files (let's say 5 rows each), so you can attach them and others could reproduce same behaviour? Otherwise it is close to impossible to tell what is going on.

Comment: Length of .dat files: 1400 rows x 4 columns | 

Number of .dat files: 1752 | 

Length of result dataframe: 2522334 rows × 4 columns |

Expected length of result dataframe (1752*1440) rows x 4 columns
expected

Comment: Did you try any kind of debugging? Did you verify that all files have 1440 rows?Does concatenation of 2 files give correct result? 50 files? ...

Comment: Just figured out three out of the 1700 files were messed up. Unfortunately, i thought i didnt have to check the files since i got them from my university. Everything is ok now. Sorry for the inconvenience.